# Visual Studio Textmate scope set color/appearance

Tags: visual-studio, colors, scope, grammar, textmate

I'm creating a new language for my new project (describing movements).
The language is quite defined, and works well. But to write/edit the description-data ("*.tzt", new invented), I'ld like syntaxhighlighting in Visual Studio editing. *There the struggle begins :-(*

I managed to set up my langage (VisualStudioExtension) on the **new file typ "TZT"**, using:

> "c:\Users\...\.vs\Extensions\TzT\Syntaxes\TzText.tmLanguage" (plist, ...)

..., but i dont find how to set my own + new scopes and define the colors.

Obviously my own scopes can't work, as the they are still undefined:

> eg: `<string >operator.joint.floating.tzt</ string>`

So far i'm using several 'reused' scopes, and get only **incidentally 3 colors**, though I've tried a lot!

> eg: `<string >comment.block.number-sign-equals.tzt</ string>`

So highlighting and grammar do work, but only with very poor and few colors.

**Which file do I have to edit, to define scope appearence and color?**

---

I think it might be kind of "theme", but couldn't find useful hint for 4 days now.

I'm using Visualstudio, NOT VisualStudioCode (90% of hits in Google are VSC) :-(

I've found https://github.com/tushortz/scopes/blob/master/C%2B%2B/c%2B%2B.txt, but this doesnt help.

Comment: Does no one know an answer, or a hint where to search?
Or ist my question not clear enough?